# How to implement class swizzling swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, class, method-swizzling

i have one view.xib file and it's having small container(container view) which holds all the controls like button/textfield, all the events of controls is handle by parent view.xib class file.

My requirement is at one place i need to add/show parent i.e view.xib completed screen. At one more place i need to add only container view. when i add/show container view only,  control's associated events/methods doesn't works.

So i thought, if i can change class of container view with parent view.xib's class, my work can be done.

**so either suggest me some other solutions or class swizzaling if it's possible to handle in this way.**

basically i am adding container view on uitableview cell's container(view) my code for same is as below

```
if  let questionContainerView = cellQuestionView.viewQuestionContainer {


    //    let questionContainerView = cellQuestionView
            cell.viewQuestionContainer.addSubview(questionContainerView)
            questionContainerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            cell.viewQuestionContainer.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: questionContainerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: cell.viewQuestionContainer, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
            cell.viewQuestionContainer.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: questionContainerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.right, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: cell.viewQuestionContainer, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
            cell.viewQuestionContainer.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: questionContainerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: cell.viewQuestionContainer, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
            cell.viewQuestionContainer.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: questionContainerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: cell.viewQuestionContainer, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
            cellQuestionView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
```

Comment: Can you add some code which can explain your problem better?

Comment: i have edited my question

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are trying to do is create a re-usable UIView with your control buttons, that you can use in different view controllers.  There is a great tutorial on Youtube entitled [iOS Basically: Reusable UIView - Programming in Swift (Part 1)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3MawJVxTgk).

Basically, you will want to create a .Xib file dedicated to the view that you want to re-use, with all the actions handled by that custom view class.  Every time you will want your custom view, you will need to instantiate it from the Xib file and manually add it as a subview onto the container view.

Good luck and happy coding!

-- edit --

Your updated code shows that this will be part of a UITableView and you are trying to add your custom view on top of a UITableViewCell. You should instead instantiate a custom UITableViewCell and register it as reusable with the table view.  This tutorial should guide you on doing just that: [Custom UITableViewCell Tutorial - TableView with Images and Text in Swift](https://www.simplifiedios.net/custom-uitableviewcell-tutorial/)

You can define your @IBAction in your custom table cell, and attach your button selectors to your action in your custom cell's nib.

Cheers!